# Save pictureBox live preview as a GIF

Tags: c#, winforms, gif, picturebox

I'm using a WebCam to show a live Preview of the webcam

I'm trying to save about 5 seconds of the live Preview as a Gif, but i cant find the right way.

This is the code I'm using to save pictureBox as jpg.

```
    private void saveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        saveFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = @"c:\picture";
        if(saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            pictureBox2.Image.Save(saveFileDialog1.FileName);
        }
```

But I want to save a GIF.

Hope you can help me.

Comment: If you are trying to do an animated GIF then I think you need to use [GifBitmapEncoder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.gifbitmapencoder(v=vs.110).aspx) or [Magick.NET](https://github.com/dlemstra/Magick.NET)

Comment: I suppose you'd have to capture a series of frames, using a timer, and then stitch those together into a GIF.  GIF is just a series of frames.

Comment: @DonBoitnott yes, That's it, But I don't know how.

Comment: There are some answers on SO about it, but it looks like you might need a 3rd party tool to do it well.  I didn't find any native ways to do it, in a quick search.